# how to gcc compile with #define in multiple files

Tags: gcc, g++

I have a project with multiple files.. I want to compile it using gcc from command line.

the directory looks like this

```
lib/
    Comp/                              contains .cpp files
    Decomp/                            contains .cpp files
    Globals.cpp
include/
    Comp/                              contains .h files
    Decomp/                            contains .h files
    Globals.h
```

some of these .h files are not paired with .cpp files

to compile this i use something like this :

```
g++ lib/Comp/* lib/Decomp/* lib/Globals.cpp -std=c++0x -o TEST
```

the problem is,I have to add some `#define`s for each .h file and i have to do it through command line. how to do this ??

also if i had to compile each file on its own and then link them. what would be the appropriate order for doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dirtiest ugliest way is that you want to use something like:

```
g++ -Iinclude lib/Comp/*.cpp lib/Decomp/*.cpp lib/Globals.cpp -o test
```

Your .cpp files should `#include <Comp/foo.h>` or whatever

The correct way to manage this is to use a makefile to build each object file and then link them together:

### Makefile

Create a a file called `Makefile` and put the following in it:

```
CXX=g++
CPPFLAGS=-Iinclude -DFOO -DBAR=1 -DSOME_STRING=\"My Name\"
CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g 

SOURCES=lib/Comp/file1.cpp \
        lib/Comp/file2.cpp \
        lib/Comp/file3.cpp \
        lib/Decomp/file1.cpp \
        lib/Decomp/file2.cpp \
        ... 

OBJ=$(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)


default: test

test: $(OBJ)
<tab>     $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJ) 

%.o: %.cpp
<tab>     $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

### NOTES

Replace file1.cpp etc. with the actual filenames in your project.  DO NOT include headers in SOURCES only your .cpp  or .cc files

If you are using sub-paths like `#include <Comp/foo.h>` or `#include "Comp/foo.h"` in  your source files then you only need to use -Iinclude in CPPFLAGS but if you are doing something like "foo.h" and foo.h is actually in include/Comp/ then add `-Iinclude/Comp` and `-Iinclude/Decomp` to the CPPFLAGS

Where it says `<tab>` make sure you use the TAB key to insert a tab (don't type the word '')

Before using this Makefile blindly .  Know that it will NOT work as is you have to correct the entries. It is offered as a starting point... Read up on writing Makefiles ... http://frank.mtsu.edu/~csdept/FacilitiesAndResources/make.htm has a good introduction

Comment: that is okay. but how to add the #defines in make file ??

Comment: use -D flag in the Preprocessor Flags ... I'll edit the answer to show some examples

Answer (score 1):

Defines can be provided on the compiler command line using -DVAR=VALUE (on Windows, presumably /DVAR=VALUE).  Note that you can *not* provide different defines for different headers as in:

```
compiler -DX=one first.h -DX=two second.h third.cc -o third.o
```

In such a case, my compiler spews warning and uses the last value of X for all source code.

Anyway, in general you should not list header files on the compilation line; prefer to include them from the implementation files (.cc/.cpp or whatever) that need them.

Be careful too - if you're changing defines to modify class definitions, inline function implementation etc. you can end up with technically and/or practically undefined behaviour.

In terms of how best to decide which objects to create and link - you probably want one object per .cc/.cpp file.  You can link those objects then specify them on the command line when compiling the file containing `main()`.